# A characteristic 2 polynomial recursion

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, modular-forms, recurrences

Let $c(n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be defined by the recursion $$c(n+4)=c(n+3)+(x^4+x^3+x^2+x)c(n)+x^n\cdot(x+x^2),$$ and the initial conditions 
$$c(0)=0,\quad c(1)=1,\quad c(2)=x,\quad c(3)=x^2.$$

**Question**: If 4 divides $n$, is $c(n)$ a sum of $c(k)$ with $k$ less than $n$?

**Remarks**:

1. I've checked that this holds up to $n=64$.
2. The recursion may seem artificial, but it arises in studying the action of the operator $U_3$ on a space of mod $2$ modular forms of level 3. This accounts for the number theory tag.

---

**VARIATION ON A THEME**

Now define another sequence $c(n)$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x]$ by the recursion
$$c(n+6)=c(n+5)+(x^6+x^5+x^2+x)c(n)+x^n\cdot(x+x^2),$$
 and the initial conditions 
$$c(0)=0,\quad c(1)=1,\quad c(2)=1,\quad c(3)=x,\quad c(4)=x^2,\quad c(5)=x^4+x^2+x.$$

**Question**: If $n$ is 0 or 2 mod 6, is $c(n)$ a sum of $c(k)$ with $k$ less than $n$?

1. I've checked that this holds through n=44.
2. This question bears the same relation to mod 2 modular forms of level 5 that my initial question bears to level 3.

TWO VARIATIONS IN CHARACTERISTIC 3

Variation 2a---Let c(n) in Z/3[x] be defined by the recursion

c(n+3)=c(n+2)-(x^3+x^2+x)c(n)+x^n*(x^3-x), and the initial conditions

c(0)=0,  c(1)=x,  c(2)=x.

If (n,3)=1, define d(n) to be c(n)+c(n+1)+c(n+2) or c(n)-c(n+1) according as n is 1 or 2 mod 3.

Question:  If n is 2 mod 9, is d(n) a Z/3-linear combo of d(k) with k less than n?

Variation 2b---Let c*(n) be c(n)-x^n with c(n) as in variation 2a. For n prime to 3 define d*(n) as in variation 2a, but with c(n) replaced by c*(n).

Question: If n is 2 mod 9, is d*(n) a Z/3 linear combo of d*(k) with k less than n?

Remarks: I've verified that these hold for n up through 83, and am confident that a variant of Peter Mueller's technique will allow one to go much further. The questions are related to calculating the kernels of U_2+I and U_2-I on the space of mod 3 modular forms of level 2, just as the earlier questions were related to calculating the kernels of U_3+I and U_5+I on the spaces of mod 2 modular forms of levels 3 and 5 respectively.

FINAL EDIT (12/7/16)

1. I've found elementary but apparently mysterious answers to the first 2 questions--see my 2 answers. The arguments are similar, and I'll randomly accept the level 3 answer.
2. I think I can answer the characteristic 3 questions too. But to avoid accusations of self-abuse I'll refrain. And though I find the question on Jordan blocks very interesting (and similar questions attached to the other recursions should also be interesting), the thread has become long and so I've deleted that question.

Comment: I edited to make it look good in LaTeX, but please check that $c(n)$ in the right set, that is, polynomials with coefficients taken mod 2.

Comment: Are you writing $\mathbb Z_2$ for $\mathbb F_2$?

Comment: @KConrad  Yes--my Z/2 got edited to Z_2, but the title shows I don't mean the 2-adics.

Comment: @paulMonsky You can edit it yourself to Z/2, select "edit" below the question.

Comment: WhaIt seems like $c(n)$ can be written as $a(n)+b(n)$ where $a(n)$ satisfies $c(n+4)=c(n+3)+(x^4+x^3+x^2+x)$ and $b(n) = x^n$. The equation for $a(n)$ is related to the curve $y^4-y^3 = x^4+x^3+x^2+x$. Do you think this perspective is unhelpful?

Comment: Do the coefficients for writing $c(n)$ as a sum of previous ones possibly stabilize?

Comment: Hi Paul, Welcome to MathOverflow. I edited your question to make it easier to read, hope you don't mind. I also fixed the Z_2 by changing it back to Z/2Z. Interesting question.

Comment: Hi Joe. I've actually been on MO for 5 years as an unregistered user, but my old computer wasn't working well, so I started a separate account on the new one. Someday I'll get them merged. If you go into the modular forms or characteristic p tags, you can find my old questions and answers.

Comment: Hi Will. Here's how the first equation arises. Let F and G be the mod 2 reductions of delta(z) and delta(3z). There is a mod 2 modular form of level 3, generating the ring of such forms, with r^4+r^3+r^2+r=F, and r^4+r^3=G,

Comment: Then U_3 takes (r+r^2)*(r^2n) into what in your notation is (r+r^2)*(a(n) evaluated at r^2). So your a(n) describe the action of U_3 on the space of (odd) forms, while the c(n) describe the action of the (locally nilpotent) operator I+U_3 on the space. The situation is similar for the second equation.

Comment: $c(0)+c(1)+c(2)+\ldots=1+x^2+x^4+\ldots=(1+x^2)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT (11/25/16)

The earlier version of this answer is sketchy, and as I've put up a complete version on arXiv (1603.03910 [math.NT], "A characteristic 2 recurrence with a Hecke algebra application"), I'm replacing my answer with references to this preprint. The argument, culminating in Theorem 2.10, involves nothing more than algebra in a ring Z/2[r], but would be mysterious to someone without a knowledge of modular forms--see the remark preceding Definition 1.1.

The final sections of the preprint give an application of Theorem 2.10 to the space K consisting of the odd mod 2 modular forms of level Gamma_0 (3) that are
killed by I+U_3. Combining Theorem 2.10 with results from arXiv:1508.07523 [math.NT], "A Hecke algebra attached to mod 2 modular forms of level 3", I show that each formal Hecke operator T_p acting on K is (uniquely) a power series in T_7 and T_13.

Answer (score 2):

A stronger property seems to hold: If $n$ fulfills the congruence condition such that $c(n)$ is expected to be a sum of $c(k)$'s with $k<n$, then the following greedy algorithm works (for both questions) up to $n=10000$: Start with $f=c(n)$. For $j$ running from $n-1$ down to $0$ replace $f$ with $f+c(j)$ whenever $f$ and $c(j)$ have the same degree. So the degree of the new $f$ drops in such a step. If we get $f=0$, then we have the requested sum. If we finish in $j=0$ and still $f\ne0$, then the algorithm fails.

A Sage code (for the second question) which checks the cases up to $n=10000$ within a few seconds is

```
K.<x> = GF(2)[]
l = [K(0), K(1), K(1), x, x^2, x^4+x^2+x]
n = len(l)
while n < 10001:
    f = l[-1] + (x^6+x^5+x^2+x)*l[-6]+x^(n-6)*(x+x^2)
    l.append(f)
    if n%6 in [0,2]:
        print n
        for j in range(n-1,0,-1):
            if f.degree() == l[j].degree():
                f += l[j]
                if f == 0:
                    break
        else:
            print "FAIL"
            break
    n += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I have further conjectures related to these recursions, that you might like to provide evidence for (or refute). Let b(n) be defined by b(n+4)=b(n+3)+z*b(n), b(0)=b(1)=0, b(2)=b(3)=1. I believe that if some c(n) in the first question sum to 0, then so do the corresponding b(n). Similarly in the second question, but now b(n+6)=b(n+5)+z*b(n), while b(0)=b(1)=b(2)=0,  b(3)=b(4)=b(5)=1.

Comment: Indeed, for $n\le1000$ this holds for both questions. However, there are many more vanishing sums among the $b(n)$'s than among the $c(n)$'s. So while the $b(n)$'s are easier (and have a not too complicated explicit expression), these vanishing sums don't seem to give a hint for the $c(n)$'s.

Comment: I have a precise conjecture about the relations between the c(n), but it isn't easily expressed in the above language, The real question is "what is the kernel of the Hecke operator I+U_3" on the space M(odd) of odd mod 2 modular forms of level 3?" The identity that you just verified indicates that this kernel lies in a subspace N2 of M(odd) that I define in my arXiv note 1508.7523. In fact I believe that the kernel is spanned by

Comment: I have to leave now; on return I'll finish this last comment.

Comment: no, put it this way--the image in N2/N1 of the kernel is epsilon*(N2/N1) where epsilon is an element of the (completed) shallow Hecke algebra whose square kills N2/N1. (In fact epsilon can be taken to be a power series in T_7, T_13, and T_5--see my note). Similar things should go on for the recursion connected with level 5.

Comment: I now have a proof, using mod 2 modular forms of levels 3 and 5, that if the c(n) sum to zero, then so do the corresponding b(n). But I still have no clue as how to answer my original questions, either by elementary or modular form methods. For this I'd want to show for the first question that the image of the kernel of I+U_3 in N2/N1 is large (and a corresponding result in level 5 for the variation question).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (12/7/16)

This answer deals with the "VARIATIONS ON A THEME". Again my earlier answer was sketchy, and I'm replacing it by references to my arXiv preprint (1612.01599 [math.NT], "A characteristic 2 recurrence attached to U_5 with a Hecke algebra application"). The entirely elementary (but seemingly mysterious) argument takes place in the few pages between Definition 1.1 and Theorem 2.11 of that note. Looking at the material preceding Definition 1.1 will help in understanding the mysteries.

The rest of the note uses Theorem 2.11 (slightly strengthened) to study the Hecke operators T_p acting on a space, K, consisting of the mod 2 modular forms of level Gamma_0 (5) annihilated by U_5+I. It's shown that each T_p, p>5, is (uniquely) in its action on K a power series with zero constant term in T_3 and T_7.